# Android. Howto read Aztec Codes from within my App?

Tags: android, user-interface, barcode, aztec-barcode

I would like to embed an Aztec Code reader into my app.
I need control over the GUI to

- place some buttons around the camera view, while reading the code
- to be able to switch the camera on / off (to save the battery)

What I found was

- ZXing - which is not reliable yet.
- Apps with an own SDK like [neoreader](http://www.neoreader.com/), which do not give me the control over my GUI.

Is there a solution for that problem? Maybe som libs? Proprietary libs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a proprietary lib from manateeworks.com
They do offer a lib, which can be used to decode Aztec Codes

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a more up-to-date answer to this question, as I was when I came across this thread a couple of hours ago:

As of [Google Play Services 8.4.0 release](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), Aztec barcodes are supported [in the vision.barcode package](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode#AZTEC). So you can now detect them from the camera in the [same way as you do for other supported types of barcode](https://developers.google.com/vision/multi-tracker-tutorial).